# AngularJS controller functions best practices

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I want to refer to my angular controller function from a template, I should put the function in `$scope`, like this:

```
[template]
<button ng-click="doSomething()"></button>

[controller]
$scope.doSomething = function(){};
```

But what about other functions (and controller variables that I don't need to be watched), the ones that I will not reference in templates.

Should I put them all in '$scope' too? 
Isn't it bad for performance? 
Is there any gotchas in declaring such functions outside of `$scope`?

Comment: You should not put them in scope. Just define them inside controller like regular functions and variables.

Comment: @MadhurAhuja like `this.myFunction=..` or `var myFunction=...`?

Comment: I prefer `function myFunction() {... }`. The problem with `var myFunction=...` is that it can be called only after where it is declared.

Comment: `this.myFunction` will be part of scope.

Comment: @charlietfi you mean this==$scope at the moment of controller instantiation?

Comment: What @charlietfl means is this: http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/ - check it out ;)

Comment: @MichaelRose Thanks man, learned something new today )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply define those as private functions within the controller's function.

Note that I also favor the function declaration syntax rather than assigning a function expression to a variable because it allows you to have all your functions declared at the bottom which reduces cognitive load when trying to see what's going on.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.exposedFn = exposedFn;

  function exposedFn() {
      fnNotExposed();
  }

  function fnNotExposed() {}

});
```